# How to replace cart data into url?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, joomla2.5, session-variables, virtuemart

I am working on a abandoned cart module where there is need to replace cart data into the url when user click on url. I am able to get cart object into the variable and also able to fetch url. now the thing is when user click on that url it shows only that page from where url is store... how do i replace cart data so that cart should also remain as it is when user click on it (eg if cart has two product than when user come after long time by click on url what i send them cart also had two product in that so user has not have to add that manually again).

```
//To Get Cart Object
$cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart();

//To Store Cart data into database
$d=json_encode($cart);

// Function to get url
function curPageURL()
    {
         $pageURL = 'http';
         if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
         $pageURL .= "://";
         if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
         {
         $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
         }
         else
         {
          $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
         }
            return $pageURL;
    }
    {
        echo curPageURL();
        exit;
    }
```

Now how do i replace cart object into the url so that user has not to add product manually.

I am using

Joomla 2.5.8

Php 5.4.3

Virtuemart 2.0.14

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you just need to add the cart to the URL as a query variable. Try something like:

```
//To Get Cart Object
$cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart();

//To Store Cart data into database
$d=json_encode($cart);

$url = curPageUrl() . '&cart=' . $d;
```

If you want the link to set the cart values, you'll need to check for the cart variable in the query string when the page loads and initialize the cart using something like this:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$imp = $app->input;
$cart = $imp->get('cart','')
if($cart!=''){
    $cart = json_decode($cart);
    // initialize the VirtualMartCart from the $cart variable
    // .
    // .
}
```

One thing to bear in mind is that several issues could arise if you are using a module to process the query string and initialize a shopping cart that may be used by other components displaying on the same page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. actually on which module i am working in that i have to send a link from where user has stop or abandon cart.. thing is, If after 24hrs I'll send him link from where he leave thus in that link only that page will open from he/she was leave and cart remain empty... than what i have to do to also cart remain as it is when user had abandon it. (eg cart has 2 product) so for solving that issue i am retrive cart object $cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart(); and store it into database using $d=json_encode($cart);

Comment: now thing is when i send link to user and if user click on it than that page should be open from where user abandon cart as well as cart data should be replace/update with cart object what i had store in database.